# extjs combo nodes

Tags: extjs

What is the meaning of the term 'nodes' w.r.t extjs? I understand the concept of a node w.r.t ..say an XML document...but what is the meaning of a node in extjs? i.e:When one does `combo.view.getNodes()` ,is the purpose to get a list of the items in the combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/DataView.html#method-Ext.DataView-getNodes

It seems it is used to get DOM nodes (i.e. HTML elements) that the combobox is build of.